# Magento 2 Unable to save product

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Using REST API it was working fine for a while and then I started getting the response:

```
{"message":"Unable to save product"}
```

When I POST a product.

Note the same product worked fine before and there is no exception in the logs (checked apache error.log and all logs for magento).

Site works fine.

Anyone else seen this?

Update: Picked up a page dump in mysql error.log. Probably something corrupt there?

Comment: Can you post your API params?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that it was a MySQL corruption. Dumping and restoring the database(s) fixed it.